# Android intent bundle always null?

Tags: java, android

I am running the below code. There are two snippets. The first is how I am setting the bundle and the second how I am retrieving it. For some reason every time i check the bundle it returns as null.

Any advice on why this is or what I have done wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.hom.app.Hom.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("WELL", "yes");
        intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieving Bundle:

```
    String well ="";
    Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
    String standard = "yes";
    if(bun != null){       
        Log.v("Bundle", "Contains data");
        well = bun.getString("WELL");
        if(well == null) well = "";
        if(well == standard) method();
    }
```

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating your intent, just put the extras right in there. you are trying to access the wrong bundle in your code above. Something like this should work.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.hom.app.Hom.class);
    intent.putExtras("WELL", "yes");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What antlersoft says about your string comparison is also true.

Comment: I have altered the string comparison thats. Rookie mistake there! I have also altered the code to the recommended above but still it returns that the bundle is empty

Comment: I've done this in a number of places and it works. Have you found a solution or would you like to expand on your code for further help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why it would be returning null, but your code would not work even if the bundle was coming through correctly because you are doing string comparison with ==

This line:

```
        if(well == standard) method();
```

Should be

```
        if(well.equals(standard)) method();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

so instead why don't you just use

```
intent.putExtra("WELL", "yes");
```