# Bundle is null after setting it in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, null, bundle

I know there are questions like:
[android-intent-bundle-always-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097267/android-intent-bundle-always-null) and [intent-bundle-returns-null-every-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106306/intent-bundle-returns-null-every-time) but there is no correct answer.

In my `Activity 1`:

```
public void goToMapView(Info info) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapViewActivity.class);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.putExtra("asdf", true);
    info.write(intent);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In Info:

```
public void write(Intent intent) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(AppConstants.ID_KEY, id);
    ... //many other attributes
    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_NAME, b);
}
public static Info read(Bundle bundle) {
    Info info = new Info();
    info.setId(bundle.getInt(AppConstants.ID_KEY));
    ... //many other attributes
    return info;
}
```

In MapViewActivity (`Activity 2`):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_NAME);
    info = Info.read(extras);
    ...
}
```

Problem is that `extras` bundle is always null. I have debugged it and Intent (`intent = getIntent()`) has all fields set to null except one indicating what class this is (`MapViewActivity`).

I've also tried putting the bundle via `intent.putExtras(b)` with the same effect.
The `intent.putExtra("asdf", true)` is for debugging reasons only - I cannot get this data too (because `getIntent()` has almost all fields set to null).

**EDIT**

The answers below are correct and working. This was my fault. I didn't correctly passed my bundle to new intent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure what "Info" is for, but I suggest making the most basic passing of data from one activity to another first before involving other data objects.

Activity1

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("asdf", true);
    info.write(intent);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
    if (bundle!=null) {
        if(bundle.containsKey("asdf") {
            boolean asdf = bundle.getBooleanExtra("asdf");
            Log.i("Activity2 Log", "asdf:"+String.valueOf(asdf));
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("Activity2 Log", "asdf is null");

    }
```

Comment: Info class is for aggregating information that I need. It has static 'read' and instance 'write' methods for better readability. The most basic passing of data is represented by putting "asdf" and this don't work. And did you mean `getBoolean` instead of `getBooleanExtra`? There is no such method. I just check your example - I get `asdf is null`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: First line needs to be `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();`

The two if statements can be combined to form can be `if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("asdf")) {` thanks to short circuiting.

Answer (score 4):

Activity 1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapViewActivity.class);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putBoolean("asdf", true);
         b.putInt(AppConstants.ID_KEY, id);
         intent.putExtras(b);

         startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

 boolean bool = extras.getBoolean("asdf");
 int m_int = extras.getInt(AppConstants.ID_KEY,-1);
```

Comment: I've tried it as it states in question at the bottom: "I've also tried putting the bundle via `intent.putExtras(b)` with the same effect". There is nothing wrong with Info class.

Comment: above shold work fine. anyway try to put values directly in intent like `intent.putExtra("asdf",false);` and `intent.putExtra(AppConstants.ID_KEY,id);`