# Data transfer with intent is not possible, because the bundle is empty

Tags: android, android-intent

My problem is sending data with intent between two classes.It is a simple case, but the application is given an error or I can not access the 2nd class(Anasayfa.class) when I send the data.I want to show the value of k (the value I get from the 1st class) in the 2nd class TextView.

> MainActivity.Class

```
Intent intentanasyf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Anasayfa.class);
                    intentanasyf.putExtra("key",k);
                    //k is an integer variable type.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(k),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(intentanasyf);
```

> Anasayfa.class

```
TextView txt_publicstuId;

Bundle bundleId;
Integer gelmisId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anasayfa);

    mMyHelper = new MyHelper(Anasayfa.this, "STUDB", null, 1);
    mSQLiteDb=mMyHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    txt_publicstuId= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpublicstuId);

    if(bundleId!=null){
        bundleId=getIntent().getExtras();
        gelmisId=bundleId.getInt("key");
        txt_publicstuId.setText(String.valueOf(gelmisId));
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundle is null after setting it in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107915/bundle-is-null-after-setting-it-in-intent)

Comment: @Vishal I checked them, but I did not get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you assigned a value to `bundleId` before checking for `null` in `Anasayfa`? Wouldn't it always be `null`? Assign some value to it before checking for null like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ... 
    bundleId=getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundleId != null && bundleId.containsKey("key")) {
        gelmisId=bundleId.getInt("key");
        txt_publicstuId.setText(String.valueOf(gelmisId));
    } else {
        // Show toast here
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking - he didn't assign  bundleId. If for some reason he hadn't defined the extra key,value pair "key" the OP would get an error when he tried to read it with `getInt("key")`. I suggest that he checks its availability first by calling `getIntent().hasExtra("key")`. Then just to be extra safe he might still want to use the overload `getIntent().getInt("key", -1)`. Then if he gets -1 returned he can react appropriately.

Comment: @Barns52 Right. Your suggestion works. Or one can use an extra check `containsKey()`.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri You are right.I did not see what was the problem for a long time.Thanks for helping me.